# The tag "rattle" should be added

Tags: discussion, support

It would be nice to be able to track questions related to Rattle .

FYI, Rattle: A Graphical User Interface for Data Mining using R
http://rattle.togaware.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the tag.~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: Thank you. Do you think this is the right place to post Rattle questions?

Comment: @AllanXu If it's about programming: stack overflow; if it's about statistics/machine learning/data-visualization: http://stats.stackexchange.com/ ; else: this website.